# Acro package: starred versions are not working?

Tags: starred-version, acro

As far as I understood from the documentation, the starred version of `\ac` command and friends shall not mark acronym as used, thus it would not appear in the acronym list. But in the example below, `\ac` and `\ac*` behave the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\newcommand*{\acro}[3]{\DeclareAcronym{#1}{short=#2,long=#3}}
\acro{RAT}{RAT}{radio access technology}
\acro{CDMA}{CDMA}{code division multiple access}

\begin{document}

\ac*{RAT}

\ac{CDMA}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding: with `\ac*{RAT}`, the acronym will appear expanded, but also expanded at the first subsequent `\ac{RAT}`.

Comment: @egreg in documentation it says "If you use the starred variant an acronym will not be marked as used" and for `only-used = true` it says "This option is true as default. It means that only acronyms that are actually used in the document are printed in the list."

Comment: I think the documentation is a bit confusing with this double usage of “used” in “marked as used” or “actually used”. But I might be wrong and this is a bug in the package.

Comment: Let's wait to see if the author of the package can help us on that clarification.

Comment: @egreg is right and my choice of words in the manual is misleading...

Comment: @cgnieder Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @cgnieder Nevertheless I think when you only use `\acl`, `\Acl` or the starred versions, printing the acronym in the acronym list may make no sense, because in reality it will not appear in the text.

Comment: @cacamailg I can see what you mean but IMHO only using `\acl` and never the acronym defeats the purpose of the package. `\acl` is meant to be used when you want to ensure the long form, in the optional argument of a figure caption for example... The same for the starred versions: they should be used in places that would destroy the order of usage in the regular text

Comment: I'll add an answer when I have a bit more time

Comment: Sometimes you just want to keep the consistency in the document, and you just use `\ac` and friends throughout the document. For example, I want to use the `\Acl` in the section title, lets say `\Acl{RAT}` and I don't know if will reuse `\ac{RAT}` in the document again or not. And if I did not believe the appearance of RAT in the acronyms list makes no sense.

Comment: @cgnieder I have a related issue with these commands. I want to cite the long form of the acronym only once and the short in the following times, but include all them in the list. Should I use `\ac` always? Or should I use `\acl` at first and later `\ac`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual is misleading or at least unclear. The starred versions do not prevent the acronyms from being written to the list of acronyms. Usage in this context means usage as far as the `\ac` macro is concerned (also, but this is probably not a good choice and maybe I should change it) as far as the `single=true` option is concerned.

If you want to ensure that an acronym is excluded from the list the easiest way seems to me to add a class to its properties and exclude the class from the list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{RAT}{
  short = RAT ,
  long = radio access technology ,
  class = invisible
}
\DeclareAcronym{CDMA}{
  short = CDMA ,
  long  =code division multiple access
}

\begin{document}

\ac{RAT}

\ac{CDMA}

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=invisible]

\end{document}
```